# Can I extract viewcount information from a list of YouTube links?

Tags: google-sheets, youtube, youtube-data-api

I have a list of YouTube URLs in a Google Sheet, and I'm trying to figure out a way to extract their viewcount information so I can total them up.

In the past, I've done this by creating a playlist of the videos in question and using [this workaround solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89717/how-to-view-total-video-view-count-of-a-youtube-playlist-channel) but unfortunately that YouTube Playlist Analyzer tool no longer exists.

I found [a potential solution](https://www.shivarweb.com/4277/scrape-export-video-information-youtube/) using ScreamingFrog's Custom Extraction tool, but unfortunately that requires purchasing a full license, which if possible I'd like to avoid since this is a one-and-done kind of task.

So if anyone knows of a way to extract number of views from YouTube URLs (as a batch or one at a time) that would be super helpful!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In former projects I've found the following approach of web scraping very simple and useful.

Loop over a list of URLs, or get the video IDs and put them into a variable.

```ini
VIDEOID="<videoid>"
```

Gather the content behind the URL.

```bash
CONTENT=$(curl --silent "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${VIDEOID}" -w "\n\n%{http_code}\n")
```

Analyze the output, find where the information is stored and just grep out the information.

```bash
COUNT=$(echo "${CONTENT}" | grep -o -P "(?<=videoViewCountRenderer).*?(?=Aufrufe)" | rev | cut -d '"' -f 1 | rev)
echo "${COUNT}"
```

You may also have a look into [Shell Script to download youtube files from playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921496/) as well into [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) and

> *Resource representation - `statistics.viewCount`*

**Thanks to**

- [How to find the last field using cut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727107/)